# DOMPDF 0.8.3 how split long vertical table

Tags: html-table, dompdf

I have table which have more rows:

[image]

This table start on new page and some rows are hidden (are not visible on next page).
I want to place table on previous page and hidden visible display to next page. I use DOMPDF 0.8.3.

I tried:

```
<table style"page-break-inside: auto;">
  <tr style="page-break: auto">
    <td>abc</td> 
    <td>cde</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="page-break: auto">
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>cde</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="page-break: auto">
    <td>abc</td> 
    <td>cde</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Do not know how to solve this, please?

Comment: Dompdf should be able to render this just fine. Can you provide more detail in your sample HTML showing more of the layout? This looks like what would happen if you have a table inside a table.

Comment: Yes, I had table inside table. I repaired it and now is all right ok. Thanks